# how can I track that my website is loaded on android device with help of jsoup?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jsoup

how can I track that my website is loaded on android device with help of jsoup?
if it is going to load with help of jsoup I dont want to provide data to it.
I dont want that some one will load my websites data into android app.

Comment: Maybe you can find your way by detecting the **user-agent** of client. So, if not a "known" user-agent, you could recuse to serve page. The problem is: **user-agent** can be easily faked.

Comment: many android devices are returning me same user-agent for Website loaded in Apps and Devices Default web browser.I am not able to use this since it can block my some genuine customers. @statosdotcom

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't say you should block'em. You're right, this is could be a tricky question. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **fairly easy** to fake the user agent using `jsoup`, or any other *crawler*. Here's an example:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.yoursite.com/")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
```

---

The default `jsoup` user agent will contain the **requested domain** (`yoursite.com`) and the **java version** (`1.8.0_05`), i.e.:

```
yoursite.com - Java version 1.8.0_05
```

Depending on the Android version, `jsoup` user agent may also look like:

```
Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; HTC Desire HD A9191 Build/GRJ90)
```

My guess is that some versions of `jsoup` rely on:

```
System.getProperty( "http.agent" );
```

---

If you still want to use this technique to deny access to your site, try using:

```
<?php
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (preg_match('/yoursite\.com[\s-]+Java.*?$/i', $userAgent)) {
    //Deny access
    die("Forbidden");
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. As I said previously, **this technique is easily bypassed and you should consider using something different**.
2. You may want to check your http access logs to find which user agents are crawling your website, find *the bad pattern* and block it.

Answer (score 0):

you could check

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

this should give a hint to whether a android device is being used

**Edit**

**this was suggested by a user in the comments before me so credit should go to them as well**